# In Java, why is printf of a Date() object wrong sometime?

Tags: java, date, datetime, printf

Sometimes the date object gives me the wrong day of the week. My code is extremely simple.

```
//Setting to 2017, April, 12th
Date dt = new Date(2017, 3, 11);
System.out.printf("%TA", dt);
```

This gives me 'WEDNESDAY' which is correct. In fact it seems to work fine for any year in the recent past and near future.

However, if I set the time to 2999, August, 5th. Which is

```
//Setting to 2999, August, 5th
Date dt = new Date(2999, 7, 4);
System.out.printf("%TA", dt);
```

It returns 'TUESDAY' when actually August the 5th 2999 is a Monday.

Why is this happening? And how do I get around it?

Cheers!

Comment: The constructor that takes year, month, and day is deprecated, and you should not use it.

Comment: You're not printing out a date in 2017 or in 2999. You're printing out dates in 3917 and 4899. Yet another reason to avoid using `java.util.Date`. You're also trying to print out August 4th rather than August 5th. (And July 11th rather than July 12th.) I would suggest you delete this question as it basically ends up as "I didn't read the documentation for the constructor I called."

Comment: Note that you would have seen both these errors by checking that the date was right first just by calling `System.out.println(dt);` first. Always assume that *your* code is probably wrong before blaming the platform - if you're going to claim that the platform is wrong, you should have done everything you can to check that first.

Comment: Not to mention that the constructor you're using has been deprecated since the previous millenium...

Comment: You should be using the java.time classes that supplanted the legacy `Date` class. See `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

The important part of your answer is already in the comments. That deprecatred constructor is confusing alright. You managed to get the month correct, which a lot of people don’t; you got the year wrong and the day-of-month wrong. Since you are using `System.out.printf()`, you may use it for checking too:

```
    // Setting to 2017, April, 12th -- NOT
    Date dt = new Date(2017, 3, 11);
    System.out.printf("%1$tm %1$te,%1$tY%n", dt);
```

This prints

```
04 11,3917
```

What a coincidence that it happens to be a Wednesday as you had expected. I would suspect this coincidence to hold for years 2001 through 2099. It doesn’t hold in February 2000. February 12 that year was a Saturday, but:

```
    // Incorrect attempt at setting to 2000, February, 12th
    dt = new Date(2000, 1, 11);
    System.out.printf("%TA%n", dt);
```

This prints

```
SUNDAY
```

> And how do I get around it?

If you can use Java 8 or later, I recommend you stay away not only from the deprecated constructor, but from the `Date` class altoghether. These days we have a bunch of better alternatives.

```
    // Setting to 2999, August, 5th
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2999, Month.AUGUST, 5);
    System.out.println(ld);
    System.out.printf("%TA", ld);
```

This prints the correct

```
2999-08-05
MONDAY
```

I usually use a `DateTimeFormatter` with the new classes, but `LocalDate` works with `System.out.printf()` too as just shown. According to the docs it works with `TemporalAccessor`, which includes `DayOfWeek`, `Instant`, `IsoEra`, `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, `LocalTime`, `Month`, `MonthDay`, `OffsetDateTime`, `OffsetTime`, `Year`, `YearMonth`, `ZonedDateTime`, `ZoneOffset` and more.